# Cannot access user controls in another website referencing from dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, user-controls, vs-web-application-project

I have a website project in visual studio 2010 with all the user controls.I build this and post build add this dll as reference to the websites that uses these user controls. Now I am trying to migrate from 2010 to 2015.I converted this website to web application to get the dll and built it.when I reference this dll in other websites it is not able to recognize the user controls from the dll. How can I access the user controls in my website after referencing to dll?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? How are you using your User Controls?

Comment: Could it be that you don't have the Framework that was used to compile the library? If you targeted a version you need to have that version on your web server.

Comment: I specified all the user controls with a tag prefix in web config.so, am accessing them as tag names in my aspx page.@techspider